# how to return my USER name

Tags: discussion, linux

please advice my USER name was deleted from the site so I cant edit my  Question

how to backup my name ?

my previos Question - [linux + generate new file with specific structure from text file what the best option](https://serverfault.com/questions/380254/linux-generate-new-file-with-specific-structure-from-text-file-what-the-best-o)

Comment: I've merged your accounts. Please consider registering with an OpenID so this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 4):

First things first - If you look at your profile, it says "Unregistered" next to your name

> yael Unregistered

on both your old and new accounts.  So the first order of business is to register your account.  Push the "login" button on the top of the screen.  You can either use an existing identity provider (Google, Facebook, OpenID) or if you prefer you can create a StackExchange identity that is independent from all of those.  That will prevent your account from disappearing in the future when you clear your browser cookies or similar mishaps occur.

After registering, you can follow the general procedure for account merges - [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).